# Programmatically draw rectangles with MonoTouch

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

I am trying to learn more about MonoTouch and so I tried out drawing with Quartz2D. I want to create an example, where I draw n-rectangles programmatically. The problem is that only the first one is drawn. I think that the second one is deleted/cleared/covered by the first one.

Here is my code:

SingleViewMTViewController.cs

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        PointF locationOne = new PointF (5, 5);
        PointF locationTwo = new PointF (5, 100);
        SizeF size = new SizeF (120, 40);

        DraggableRectangle tView = new DraggableRectangle (locationOne, size, UIColor.Yellow);
        DraggableRectangle tView2 = new DraggableRectangle (locationTwo, size, UIColor.Brown);

        DraggableRectangle[] views = new DraggableRectangle[2];
        views [0] = tView;
        views [1] = tView2;

        View.AddSubviews (views);
    }
```

DraggableRectangle.cs

```
public class DraggableRectangle : UIView
{
    private CGPath path;
    private PointF _targetLocation;
    private SizeF _size;
    private UIColor _fillColor = UIColor.Brown;

    public DraggableRectangle (PointF targetLocation, SizeF size)
    {
        _targetLocation = targetLocation;
        _size = size;

        RectangleF frameRect = new RectangleF (_targetLocation.X, _targetLocation.Y, _size.Width, _size.Height);
        this.Frame = frameRect;
        this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear; //without this, nothing is drawn
    }

    public DraggableRectangle (PointF targetLocation, SizeF size, UIColor fillColor):this(targetLocation,size)
    {
        _fillColor = fillColor;
    }

    public override void Draw (RectangleF rect)
    {
        //base.Draw (rect);
        //works without base-call?

        //get graphics context
        using (CGContext gctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ()) {

            //set up drawing attributes
            _fillColor.SetFill ();

            //create geometry
            path = new CGPath ();

            path.AddRect (new RectangleF (_targetLocation.X, _targetLocation.Y, _size.Width, _size.Height));

            path.CloseSubpath ();

            //add geometry to graphics context and draw it
            gctx.AddPath (path);        
            gctx.DrawPath (CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);   
        }       
    }
```

Is there a better way to draw independent rectangles with MonoTouch? Or could please someone explain, what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** Thats btw. the best output I can achieve, but thats just not correct for "Yellow" and "Brown"
http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=81bfea-1329755225.png
http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=81bfea-1329755225.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, both of your rectangles are drawn. The problem is your `_targetLocation.Y` value. You are setting the same **Y** value for both your view's `Frame` and its rectangle to be drawn in its `Draw` method.

So basically, your rectangle is drawn outside the bounds of the view. Your "brown" view's height is 40pt, while its rectangle is drawn at Y=100 (below its visible portion).

You have to differentiate these values, since a view's location is always relative to its parent's coordinates.

Edit: a pseudo-code example.

The following line:

```
path.AddRect (new RectangleF (_targetLocation.X, _targetLocation.Y, _size.Width, _size.Height));
```

Should be something like:

```
    path.AddRect (new RectangleF ({Frame.Width >= something >= 0}, 
{Frame.Height >= something >= 0}, width, height);
```

Edit #2:

If I change the rect of the path, with the following:

```
path.AddRect (new RectangleF (0f, 0f, _size.Width, _size.Height));
```

Here is what I get...

[image: Two rects]

Comment: Sounds interesting, could you please give me some sample-code? Just enough so I know, where I have to change what. As I am not 100% sure i understood, what you meant. Especially, why is it drawn below the frame?

Comment: Wow - that was fast :) Many thanks. Just one more question: On what depends the FrameSize? So what is your "something" in your code-example?

Comment: Awesome - works like a charm! Thousand thanks! Do you know any good tutorials for this stuff? Where things like the Frames etc. are covered?